# vue.js: replacement for async hooks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

Let's assume that I write a vue.js component and I want to use lifecycle hook (in this case 'destroyed') that includes some async operation. I don't want to leave the hook before the async operation is fully committed. One option is to use the async-await feature of Javascript at all.

```
    export default {
      name: 'someComponent',
      data() {
        return {
          ...,
        };
      },
      async destroyed() {
         await someAsyncOperation()
     }
    }
```

I want to ask if there is any way to do it without async-await (maybe promises).

Comment: If i may ask what speeks against async/await?

Comment: Nothing. It's a great feature. But, I was wondering what if I use older version of js (ECMA 5, for example) that don't have this feature. How can I make them do this job?

Comment: i think using `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook with old version of asynchronous syntax  should fit to your need

Comment: you seem to be under the impression that async/await makes the async call synchronous. That's not the case. The code still runs asynchronously and Vue will not wait for it to run.

Comment: Pretty sure it simply won't work; at least, it won't wait for the asynchronous code to execute before destroying. But if you need to use async/await on older browsers, why not use Babel and webpack to abstract that problem away for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue doesn't care or acknowledge that your lifecycle hooks are asynchronous, it will not wait await them.  Consider the example below.  If the API worked the way that you interpreted it, you would not see the new `thing` until after the `console.log` printed.  However, it appears immediately.

Additionally, the Vue docs don't state that the lifecycle hooks are asynchronous.  It doesn't say that they are `async` and it doesn't provide an option for a callback to to infer when the hook has completed.

This is in contrast to some of the other hook APIs (like animations) that Vue has.

```js
const $timeout = d => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));

const thing = {
  template: "<div>Count: {{text}}</div>",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "foo"
    };
  },
  async created() {
    await $timeout(1000);
    console.log("hello");
  },
  async destroyed() {
    await $timeout(1000);
    console.log("goodbye");
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    thing
  },
  data() {
    return {
      things: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addThing() {
      this.things.push({});
    },
    removeThing() {
      this.things.pop();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="addThing">+</button>
  <button @click="removeThing">-</button>
  <div v-for="thing in things">
    <thing></thing>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point. What you actually mean is that async/await is a syntactic sugar that makes Promises easier. It's not a new ability in the language.